# Java Wikitext Parser

Tags: java, parsing, mediawiki

Any ideas for a nice parser with an easy to use API that is configurable? I'm looking to feed it data such as http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=San%20Francisco, choose sections of data I want, and output custom html for each unique type of element? Java would be preferred, but if there's a PHP/js solution that is compatible with most (99%+) wikitext, that would be okay as well.

Comment: To what do you want to parse the wikitext? Or: How do you want to customize the HTML?

Comment: I want to convert the wikitext to html, but be able to change the kind output ie italizing ('') to something else.

Comment: Can't you do that afterwards, i.e. changing <i> to something else?

Comment: Less conversion passes, the better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Sweble](http://sweble.org/) is probably the best Java parser of wikitext. It [claims to be 100% compliant](http://sweble.org/wiki/Sweble_Wikitext_Parser/Features) with wikitext, but I seriously doubt that. It parses wikitext into an abstract syntax tree that you then have to do something with (like convert it to HTML).

[There is a page on mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) that lists wikitext parsers in various programming languages. I don't think any of them do 99+% of wikitext though. In general parsing wikitext is a really complex problem. Wikitext isn't even formally defined anywhere outside of the MediaWiki parser itself.

Comment: Excellent answer, I'd have written the same :-)

Comment: How do you even use Sweble? I looked at it before, but I can't find an api to access it within Java and I can't parse anything through invoking the jar through the command line.

Comment: Yeah, their documentation isn't great. Did you see this example: http://sweble.org/wiki/Sweble_Wikitext_Parser/Guide/Demo_Project?

Comment: I saw the example, but I tried a lot of jars from http://mojo.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases/org/sweble/wikitext/
All of them say "no main manifest attribute"

Answer (score 15):

This question was answered years ago, but I wanted to save future visitors the effort I had to take to figure out how to use Sweble.

You can try the documentation at their site, but I couldn't figure it out. Just look at the example source code. Download the source jar for swc-example-basic at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sweble/wikitext/swc-example-basic/2.0.0/swc-example-basic-2.0.0-sources.jar and look at App.java and TextConverter.java.

Basically, to parse a page and convert it to another form, you first add the following dependency to your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sweble.wikitext</groupId>
        <artifactId>swc-engine</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, do the following:

```
public String convertWikiText(String title, String wikiText, int maxLineLength) throws LinkTargetException, EngineException {
    // Set-up a simple wiki configuration
    WikiConfig config = DefaultConfigEnWp.generate();
    // Instantiate a compiler for wiki pages
    WtEngineImpl engine = new WtEngineImpl(config);
    // Retrieve a page
    PageTitle pageTitle = PageTitle.make(config, title);
    PageId pageId = new PageId(pageTitle, -1);
    // Compile the retrieved page
    EngProcessedPage cp = engine.postprocess(pageId, wikiText, null);
    TextConverter p = new TextConverter(config, maxLineLength);
    return (String)p.go(cp.getPage());
}
```

The TextConverter is a class you'll find in the examples I mentioned above. Customize it to do whatever you want. For example, the following makes sure all bold text is surrounded by "**":

```
public void visit(WtBold b)
{
    write("**");
    iterate(b);
    write("**");
}
```

There are a bunch of visit methods on that class for each type of element that you'll encounter.

Answer (score 2):

I just had success with Bliki: https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki/wiki/Mediawiki2HTML

Bliki is what is used by XWiki and usage is very easy:

```
String htmlText = WikiModel.toHtml("This is a simple [[Hello World]] wiki tag");
```

Here is a list of downloads:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/info/bliki/wiki/bliki-core/

But it is much easier to use this with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use XWiki's rendering engine (http://rendering.xwiki.org). Here's an example of how you'd parse some mediawiki content:

```
// Initialize Rendering components and allow getting instances
EmbeddableComponentManager componentManager = new EmbeddableComponentManager();
componentManager.initialize(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

// Get the MediaWiki Parser
Parser parser = componentManager.getInstance(Parser.class, "mediawiki/1.0");

// Parse the content in mediawiki markup and generate an AST (it's also possible to use a streaming parser for large content)
XDOM xdom = parser.parse(new StringReader("... input here"));

// Perform any transformation you wish to the XDOM here
...

// Generate XHTML out of the modified XDOM
WikiPrinter printer = new DefaultWikiPrinter();
BlockRenderer renderer = componentManager.getInstance(BlockRenderer.class, "xhtml/1.0");
renderer.render(xdom, printer);

// The result is now in the printer object
printer.toString();
```

See more examples at http://rendering.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/GettingStarted

Hope it helps.